# Make text resize on window resize without going to newline

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've this bootstrap top bar

http://jsfiddle.net/MmcEj/

and I want to make the text contained in

```
<ul class="nav image-title-container">
    <li class="hidden-desktop image-title icon">somelongtitlesomelongtitlesomelongtitlesomelongtitlesomelongtitle</li>
</ul>
```

be as large as possible until it reaches the rigth button and wrap when you resize the window without having to use the % width since most of the time it doesn't use the whole available space nor having the text going into a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using media queries. Try this http://www.mrgeek.me/technology/tutorials/web-design/how-to-make-text-responsive-in-bootstrap/

Comment: I've used media query to change the max-width at the end, not a perfect solution but the less worse one.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to use [FitText](http://fittextjs.com/)

Comment: That will just make font smaller, I want it to be cut with ellipsis